# Como pegar parametro de um POST em aplicação REST

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

Iniciei uma aplicação Rest e tenho uma classe java **createPost**

```
    POST
    @Path("/post/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static String createPost(@FormParam("loopID") String loopID) throws IOException {
         ConnectDAO dao = ConnectDAO();
         Post post = new Post();
         post.setLoopId(loopID);
    }
```

Onde ele vai receber por parametro esse "valor".

No javascript tenho que criar um serviço já que utilizo angular chamado createPost, e ele vai fazer o "POST".

```
createPost: function(loopID) {
            if (!loopID) {
                hyatt.ui.view.alert('There is no file to upload. Please choose a file.');
            } else {
                return http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url + '/post/',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    },
                    transformRequest: formData
                });
            }
            // This forces the break of execution.
            throw new Error('The UploadService service needs a file and this file cannot be a video');


        },
```

Acima estou recebendo por parametro o valor que quero passar para o JAVA.Como posso estar fazendo isso? tentei com o @FormParam mas não deu certo.

Obs: Não estou podendo no momento pegar via @PathParam já que a url chama um serviço externo.

Quem puder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim.

```
@POST
@Path("/post/")
@Produces("application/json ; charset=UTF-8")
public String createPost(String loopId){
    ConnectDAO dao = ConnectDAO();
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setLoopId(loopID);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: restornou pra mim o seguinte erro: 204 - No Content. Acredito que tenha resolvido no sentido de pegar o parametro...

Comment: Vc debugou o codigo java pra ver se o método chegou a ser executado e se o parametro loopId foi preenchido?

Comment: sim! de qualquer forma consegui assim no JS
var data = '&idLoop=' + idLoop + '&title=' + title + '&folderID=' + folderID;
                return http.post(urlYapmo + '/post/' +
                    hyatt.date.getParameterTimeStamp(), data);